# How to clear JavaScript timeout using the if else statement if condition is true

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I tried using some JavaScript timing with an `if` statement. The script executed but I set another `if` statement that clears the timeout if the condition is true.  It's not working.

Code:

```
var timeing = setTimeout("timelet()");
if(hour==true && min==true){
    clearTimeout(timeing);
    return true;
}
```

How do I clear the timeout if the condition is true?

Comment: Your problem is that your timeout is NO timeout. You have to give the milliseconds as second parameter or else it will be executed DIRECTLY and cannot be avoided / disabled /cleared.

Comment: Don't create the timeout if youre going to clear it based on the condition?

Comment: Really! `if (hour && min) { do stuff }else{ setTimeout(timelet) }`

Comment: @megawac I do not think that is a part of a "solution" here. The issue is something else and the problem definitely is not setting the second parameter. I often have the case that timeouts shall not be executed but are set anyway.

Comment: There is no probleme using setTimeout() and  a IF statement but you didn't really explain what you want to do.

You should check it before to set it... but clearTimeout(timeing); is the right way.

Comment: @androidavid - That's not true, the timeout still defers execution and can be canceled.

Comment: @adaneo: You're right in fact. But it's not standardized so it's not good practice. Though saying that your code should properly work. For most cases it wont. There is no ECMA Script Definition for setTimeout so you would definetely have to look how every browser handles this issue. The W3C tries to standardize it but even there it is not clearly given what happens.

Comment: @androidavid - why wouldn't it be standardized, it's what a timeout does, it defers the execution ?

Comment: @androidavid http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout: "Let timeout be the second method argument, or zero if the argument was omitted." Are you suggesting that a zero timeout *won't* defer execution in some case?

Comment: @apsillers: Thanks for that link! Did not find that in the ECMA-262 pdf - sorry bothering.

Comment: The HTML5 spec even says that the minimum delay is 4ms, and all browsers comply with that, or more, so it's never executed right away, and without a time, it at least defers the execution until the thread is free.

Comment: @androidavid `setTimeout` is out of scope for the ECMAScript spec -- it's part of what [the EMCAScript spec calls the "host environment"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4) ("*the existing system is said to provide a host environment of objects and facilities, which completes the capabilities of the scripting language*"). Those behaviors and APIs (in the case of Web browsers) are specified by the W3C and WHATWG.

Comment: @adaneo: Could you provide the link to that paragraph? I would be interested.

Comment: @androidavid http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers: "If the currently running task is a task that was created by the setTimeout() method, and timeout is less than 4, then increase timeout to 4." Even without that 4ms-buffer, however, a true zero-length timeout would still defer execution until the current task completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what you are trying to do, but either this;

```
// set the time out and then check and clear it every time its run
function timelet() {
    // some stuff

    if(hour==true && min==true){
        clearTimeout(timeing);
    }
}
var timeing = setTimeout(timelet(), 1000);
```

OR

```
// don't set the time out if not required
if(hour==true && min==true) {
    // do something
} else {
    var timeing = setTimeout(timelet(), 1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is definitely here:

```
if(hour==true && min==true)
```

Try to figure out this combined statement becomes true.